# Ajaxy - I am not redirected to the the page I specify in the hash / if I reload the page when I initialize ajaxy

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

i am using the Ajaxy jQuery plugin: http://balupton.com/sandbox/jquery-ajaxy/

when i visit http://www.example.com/#/foo/ the content of foo does not show up. instead the content of my index.php in the root is being shown.

this is how i initialze ajaxy:

```
var $body = $(document.body),
    $menu = $('#wrapper'),
    $content = $('#wrapper')
$.Ajaxy.configure({
    'Controllers': {
        '_generic': {
            request: function(){
                // Loading
                $body.addClass('loading');
                // Done
                return true;
            },
            response: function(){
                // Prepare
                var Ajaxy = $.Ajaxy; var data = this.State.Response.data; var state = this.state||'unknown';
                // Title
                var title = data.title||false; // if we have a title in the response JSON
                if ( !title && this.state||false ) title = 'jQuery Ajaxy - '+this.state; // if not use the state as the title
                if ( title ) document.title = title; // if we have a new title use it
                // Loaded
                $body.removeClass('loading');
                // Return true
                return true;
            },
            error: function(){
                // Prepare
                var Ajaxy = $.Ajaxy; var data = this.State.Error.data||this.State.Response.data; var state = this.state||'unknown';
                // Error
                var error = data.error||data.responseText||'Unknown Error.';
                var error_message = data.content||error;
                // Log what is happening
                window.console.error('$.Ajaxy.Controllers._generic.error', [this, arguments], error_message);
                // Loaded
                $body.removeClass('loading');
                // Done
                return true;
            }
        },
        'page': {
            classname: 'ajaxy-page',
            matches: /^\/pages\/?/,
            data: {ajaxy : true},
            request: function(){
                // Prepare
                var Ajaxy = $.Ajaxy;
                console.log(this);
                // Adjust Menu
                $menu.find('.active').removeClass('active');
                // Hide Content
                $content.stop(true,true).fadeOut(400);

                console.log(arguments)
                // Return true
                return true;
            },
            response: function(){
                // Prepare
                var Ajaxy = $.Ajaxy; var data = this.State.Response.data; var state = this.state; var State = this.State;
                // Adjust Menu
                $menu.children(':has(a[href*="'+State.raw.state+'"])').addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
                // Show Content
                var Action = this;
                console.log(data);
                $content.html(data.content).fadeIn(400,function(){
                    Action.documentReady($content);
                });
                // Return true
                return true;
            }
        }
    },
    root_url: url + '/',
    relative_url: url + '/',
    redirect: true
});
```

thanks in advance

lukas

Comment: try to give less code and more explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution. the problem was the "matches" option for the controller:

```
matches: /^\/pages\/?/
```

i changed it to:

```
matches: /\//
```

thanks anyway

lukas